# Stuck on partitioning disk using bootcamp with early 2015 model macbook air, 480 gb auro pro x2 SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition, ssd

I am attempting to create a 100 GB partition for windows 10 on my macbook air via Bootcamp Assistant. I have been stuck on "partitioning disk...", with the load bar completely full for some time now. I have a 64 GB USB drive inserted, which I believe was necessary for the partition.

Additionally, I have just installed a 480 GB SSD from OWC. When using disk utility my SSD, the USB drive, the iso images for windows 10 as well as the boot camp partition show up. However, the bootcamp partition is in light grey and says it is not mounted. [image: Disk Utility screenshot]

My diskutil list call results with the following:[image: diskutil list from Mac terminal]

If anyone could let me know what I am doing wrong or what I can do to fix this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The selected 'disk' is just an image of a "CD" - [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) is 'Joliet' or 'CD format' in loose terms.

Comment: Okay, so should I continue waiting for my drive to partition? It's been going for quite awhile now.

Comment: I'd at least give it a chance. I'd always say on these occasions your patience ought to be directly proportional to the time since your last full backup.

Comment: Alright will do. But you're telling me that nothing is jumping out about my diskutil list?

Comment: As it stands, it shows 'no progress'... but I've never tried getting the list whilst in the middle of an operation such as this. I have no clue at what point it will reflect the new map.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything...

Comment: You have got past this point.  Please close the question.

Comment: I recommend trying an alternative program to disk utility. The bootcamp partitions may be in a file system that can't be read by disk utility. NTFS is often the default file system for C which is unreadable in disk utility. I can't guarantee this is the issue but I recommend trying an alternative program.